How to use PowerShell script to load and call a C++ DLL's function Myfunction that accept parameter as (LPINT, LPSTR, LPINT)
I tried the below script to call the function MyFunction(LPINT, LPSTR,LPINT)
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class CFunctions {
[DllImport("D:\\Test\\MySample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int MyFunction(IntPtr a , string data , IntPtr b);     
}
"@

 # Below is the Function call to "MyFunction"

$x   =  21
$data_string = "Hello"
$y =  0

$result = [CFunctions]::MyFunction($x,$data_string, $y)
Write-Output "MyFunction return: $result"`

I believe [CFunctions]:: MyFunction($x,$data_string, $y) is accepting the value of x and y instead of their address.
Function "MyFunction" accepts the first and third parameters as LPINT. How to pass the address of x and y in the below function call?
[CFunctions]::MyFunction($x,$data_string, $y)  


To pass the address of variables to a C++ DLL function from PowerShell, you need to use IntPtr to represent pointers and Marshal class to convert variables to pointers.

@madhawapolkotuwa Could you please give an example for the same? How to Marshell? I tried a lot but PowerShell keep crashing.

What version of PowerShell are you running? $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
